# Revert a project in SVN to a previous version and make it the HEAD version

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control

I have a issue with my SVN version control: The project is at the svn's version 130, and due to a error I need to revert it to the version 128, and make it the HEAD version (that is: discard the changes made in the versions 129 and 130).

I'm using Subclipse how can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you how to use Subclipse (don't have Eclipse installed at home).  But from the command line, you'd do this:

```
svn merge -r130:128 ssh://whatever/your/url/is
svn ci -m "Rollback!"
```

Comment: That would revert head not revision 130 as the author states. What if somebody else checked-in revision 131, then you would revert his changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use svn merge:

```
svn merge -r130:129 url
```

Then svn commit.

Comment: That would only rollback the changes in r130.  Also, you need to provide a URL.

Comment: added url. but i don't agree with head thing you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled about this problem. I then tried to make a reverse merge with subclipse and ended up in a synchronization hell. :-)

In Eclipse 'replace with' is your friend here! Just right-click on the folder in the package explorer, right-click and choose 'Replace With...' -> 'Revision or URL' and Eclipse will do what you want. After that you have to do a commit.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what  i was looking for.